# How can i list random author?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, author, list-authors

Im listing current category of  all author list but I want to list random author list from current category.

I was try 'order' => 'RAND', RAND code its not worked.

My Code:

```
function getCurrentCatID(){
  global $wp_query;
  if(is_category() || is_single()){
    $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
  }
  return $cat_ID;
}

$current_category_ID = getCurrentCatID();
$current_cat_id = $current_category_ID;

$author_array = array();
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'cat' => $current_cat_id,
  'orderby' => 'author',
  'order' => 'asc',
  'posts_per_page' => '10',
);
$cat_posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) :
  if (!in_array($cat_post->post_author,$author_array)) {
    $author_array[] = $cat_post->post_author;
  }
endforeach;

foreach ($author_array as $author) :
  $auth = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
  $auth_link = get_userdata($author)->user_login;
  $autid= get_userdata($author)->ID;
  $link = get_author_posts_url($autid);
  echo ''. get_avatar( $autid, '46' ).'';
  echo "<a class='sidebar-aut' href='$link";
  echo "'>";
  echo '<h6>'.$auth.'</h6>';
  echo "</a>";
  echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
  echo "<br />";
endforeach;
```

Comment: You are trying to list all the authors from a particular category. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Codex lists `rand` as the `orderby` string](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), not `RAND`. I suspect that either works but I haven't checked. But that isn't how I'd do this. I'd lean toward something like...

```
$current_category_ID = getCurrentCatID();
$current_cat_id = $current_category_ID;

$author_array = array();
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'cat' => $current_cat_id
);
$cat_posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) :
  if (!in_array($cat_post->post_author,$author_array)) {
    $author_array[] = $cat_post->post_author;
  }
endforeach;

shuffle($author_array); // randomize
```

Database `ORDER BY` isn't terribly efficient. `ORDER BY RAND` is especially inefficient. That code does the sorting in PHP on a smaller array, so it should perform better.

Comment: i have a question again. How can i list 5 or 10 author? This code listing many authors. I would like to restrict the number of authors.(e.g. just list random 5 author)

Comment: Use [`array_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to pull out however many you want.